# NoSuchMethodError for com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultAllocator

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-studio-3.3

I am using

> com.amazon.android:exoplayer-ui:r2.5.4

in my project I just upgraded IDE to Android Studio 3.3.1.
 in my `build.gradle` I have below code for compile

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

While trying to build, I get this error:

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED AGPBI:
>   {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported
>   starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player$EventListener.onLoadingChanged(boolean)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>     Failed to transform file 'classes.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-is-debuggable=true,
>     dexing-min-sdk=21} using transform DexingTransform
>     Error while dexing.

When I change the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`, it gets build successfully but the app crashes with following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.mypackage, PID: 4374
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method (Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultAllocator;IIJJLcom/google/android/exoplayer2/util/PriorityTaskManager;)V
>   in class Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl; or its
>   super classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl' appears in
>   /data/app/mypackagename/base.apk:classes5.dex)

Any suggestions?

**project build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
    System.properties['com.android.build.gradle.overrideVersionCheck'] = 'true'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

    }

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

**app build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ‘myAppId’
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26

        versionCode 31
        versionName "1.3.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                                     "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        sourceSets {
            androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g" 
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
              abortOnError false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version'
    }
}


dependencies {

implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:23.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.8.5'
    implementation('com.amazon.android:exoplayer-ui:r2.5.4') {
        exclude module: 'exoplayer-core'
    }
    api 'com.amazon.android:exoplayer-core:r2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.amazon.android:exoplayer-hls:r2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.amazon.android:exoplayer-dash:r2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.amazon.android:extension-okhttp:r2.5.4'
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'

    implementation('android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-rc1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
        exclude group: 'android.arch.persistence.room', module: 'runtime'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-utils'
    }
    implementation('android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-rc1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-utils'
    }
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-rc1'
    implementation('android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-rc1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-ui'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-utils'
    }
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-rc1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-rc1"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: please post your both build.gradle file, module level as well as app level

Comment: @VikaS Updated the post.

Comment: upgrade your SDK and associated lib to 28...Also upgrade your Gradle to `gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`...then rebuild app...then `Invalidate Cache/Restart` from File menu

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: @VikaS No. Changed `compileSdkVersion 28` . Gradle was already 4.10, still the same errors!

Comment: @Pdroid What was solution for this error? I am facing such issue

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in app level `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.3'
```

upgrade your SDK and associated lib to 28...Also upgrade your Gradle to `gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`...then `rebuild` app...then `Invalidate Cache/Restart` from `File` menu.

If still not working then add below code and follow steps of `rebuild` and  `Invalidate Cache/Restart`

```
implementation ('react-native-track-player') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.exoplayer'
}
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.3'
```

Comment: I don't use `react-native-track-player` dependancy. Why to add now?